# How to pass GET variables from php to php on another server

Tags: php, post, get

In a php script I am receiving some data:

```
$data = $_POST['someData'];
```

How can I do something like this:

```
goToThisUrl( "http://someDomain.com/someScript.php?data = ".$data );
```

or if it is easier how can I do it by POST?

BTW.
This is not happening in a browser, the first php script is getting called by a cart when the order is paid for (if it makes any difference)

Comment: Do you really need to call off to another php script like this? If `someScript.php` is on the same domain, it would be a lot easier to include it using `require` and simply call the functions directly.

Comment: @Chris The question title says "to php on another server"

Comment: You want cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

Replace `goToThisUrl` with the real function `file_get_contents` and remember to `urlencode($data)` and that would work just fine.

If you want to POST the data instead, look at cURL. Typing "[php] curl post" into the search box will get you the code.

Comment: You can also POST with `file_get_contents` using `stream_context_create`, which is far simpler than cURL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the user there, then:

```
header('Location: http://someDomain.com/someScript.php?data='.$data);
exit;
```

Or if you just want to call the other server, you can do:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://someDomain.com/someScript.php?data='.$data);
```

Both assume data is already a urlencoded string, you might want to use `'data=' . urlencode($data)` or just `http_build_query($data)` otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
  $qs = urlencode($key) . "=" . urlencode($val) . "&";
}
$base_url = "<url here>";
$url = $base_url . "?" . $qs;
header('Location: $url'); exit();
```

Comment: Change that to only `urlencode($val)` in the loop and not the entire query string and it'd be good. As is, you destroy the query string by encoding the `=` and `&` symbols.

Comment: @Dan you'd also want `urlencode($key)` to be safe, or simply `$qs = http_build_query($_POST);`